# Is there a class level annotation for @JsonProperty

Tags: java, jackson

Is there a class level annotation for `jackson`'s `@JsonProperty` ? Without knowing what field names are in the class, I can be able to annotate the class with a annotation and it will map it for me automatically?

Currently I have to annotate each field with a JsonProperty, is there something I can do at the class level that servers the same purpose?

```
public class myEntity() {

@JsonProperty("banner")
private String banner;

@JsonProperty("menu")
private String menu;

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@JsonProperty is not a class-level annotation, and you don't need to mark your class with any annotation. If you provide your class name as an argument to parser it will know how to map it according to your getter methods. It is as if every getter method has been marked with @JsonProperty without any argument.

Comment: The parser im using is the JacksonEncoder and JacksonDecoder. 
.encoder(new JacksonEncoder()).decoder(new JacksonDecoder())
 .target(myEntity.class);

Are you saying I just have to add the getter and setters then it should do it by itself? Because I already have public getters and setters for the fields, but it didnt work.

Comment: Look at ObjectMapper class and its methods: readValue(), writeValueAsString(), convertValue(). that should work

Comment: @PhoonOne you would need to define what "does not work" means. But as far as `@JsonProperty` goes, no, the POJO classes do NOT need anything to mark them as serializable; nor do properties if you have public getter or setter.

Answer (score 12):

Class level annotation

```
@JsonRootName("Response")
public class SuperResponse {
...
}
```

Result:

```
<Response>
...
</Response>
```

Comment: it's not working for me. is there any alternative for it

Comment: Why is this a solution to field names within a class?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to solutions from [Answer by @MicaelGantman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35275329/1357094) that leverage getters/setters, making the fields `public` (even without getters/setters) also works (without any field or class-level Annotation).  `public final` also works (when shielding the fields more).

Answer (score -1):

```
@JsonRootName(value = "user")
public class User {
public int id;
public String name;
}
```